# How and where is my viminfo option set?

Tags: vim

As far as I can tell I don't set `viminfo` anywhere, yet it is set.

```
:verbose set viminfo?
```

prints

```
  viminfo='100,<50,s10,h,rA:,rB:
    Last set from ~/vimfiles/vimrc
```

But `~/vimfiles/vimrc` doesn't set it.

Even if I let `~/vimfiles/vimrc` set it to an arbitrary value, `viminfo` will still be set to `'100,<50,s10,h,rA:,rB:`.

Why is that and how can I set/unset `viminfo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem too.
It turn out that the viminfo option is overwritten by the nocompatible flag. Since it overwrite other option too, it is better to place "set nocompatible" at very start of your vimrc file. This solved my issue with viminfo configuration.

Answer (score 35):

You can set `viminfo` by *temporary* and *permanent* way:

- For *temporary* way, you can input the setting command by `:set viminfo=xxxx`
- For *permanent* way, you can input the setting in your `~/.vimrc` in Linux and `$VIM/_vimrc` in Windows

My setting as below:

```
set viminfo=%,<800,'10,/50,:100,h,f0,n~/.vim/cache/.viminfo
"           | |    |   |   |    | |  + viminfo file path
"           | |    |   |   |    | + file marks 0-9,A-Z 0=NOT stored
"           | |    |   |   |    + disable 'hlsearch' loading viminfo
"           | |    |   |   + command-line history saved
"           | |    |   + search history saved
"           | |    + files marks saved
"           | + lines saved each register (new name for ", vi6.2)
"           + save/restore buffer list
```

And, [the most important is `set viminfo=xxx` should come after `set nocompatible`](https://superuser.com/questions/693668/why-viminfo-setting-dosent-work-in-vim)

Comment: This is extremely useful, thanks.  As an aside I've set MYVIMRC to /root/.gnicholl/.vimrc (we're sharing root on the box - yes, I know!), but it is being ignored - I have to alias vi to vim -u /root/.gnicholl/.vimrc to get it to work - any idea about that?

Comment: How were you able to decipher the viminfo format? Is there an easy to read table somewhere? What other options are possible?

Comment: @425nesp, if you are talking about the vim format in my answer, I do that manually. In daily programming, I'm using `Tabularize` (https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular). BTW, using `ctrl+v` to modify lines

Comment: Ah, sorry I was referring to the symbols that `viminfo` accepts. I couldn't find the right help page at first. `:help 'viminfo'` is what I was looking for. The table is cool too though! :D

Comment: @425nesp, first you need check if `viminfo` is actived in the `:ver` (`+viminfo` means enabled). And you can try `:h viminfo` or `:h viminfofile` (without single quotas), it will show something like `10. The viminfo file ...`. BTW, my vim is `v8.2.314`

Comment: A warning: If someone losts data in clipboard, please check if the "lines saved each register" is too small or the maximum memory like "s10" is set. It is painful to lost hundreds lines of code.

Comment: The last sentence saved me some headaches

Answer (score 0):

That's the default value. `:verbose` is not really helpful, here, and that behaviour is not documented AFAIK but it always does that for default values.

I suggest you read `:help 'viminfo'` for the meaning of the values of the `viminfo` option and how to `:set` it (not `:let`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already have read `help viminfo` and I do understand the meaning of the various options. The problem is that even if I `:set viminfo='100,n/some/path/vinfo` (in my vimrc file), vim won't change the actual value of `viminfo`.

Comment: Just a note, `:help viminfo` and `:help 'viminfo'` take you to different help pages. The options are documented at `:help 'viminfo'`.

Answer (score -3):

**Warning: Better not setting these two variables: "<50,s10"**

They are the maximum lines and maximum memory allowed, it will clear your clipboard without any warning if the number of lines exceeds!